# Localhost not displaying Nuxt app and showing 503 error (Service Unavailable), how do I fix this?

Tags: windows, nuxt.js, localhost, nuxt3

**Environment**

Operating System: Windows 11

Node Version: v20.9.0

Nuxt Version: 3.6.1

After running `npm run dev` command in my vs code terminal, it displays the local host link: `http://localhost:3000/` and network link.
When I click on the local host link, the Nuxt app does not display. Instead, it is stuck on the Nuxt screen forever.

[Nuxt default screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pycyG.png)

In the console, this error is displayed: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)` `GET http://localhost:3001/ 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Comment: did you check http://localhost:3001  ?

Comment: Yes I did, did not work too. I also tried opening in incognito mode, still did not work

Comment: try to create an index.vue under /pages and then try again, if it works.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I already have an index.vue under /pages. But I deleted it and made a new one after seeing your comment and it still does not work.